# Headlights come on then go off

Tags: electrical, chevrolet, headlight, trailblazer

When I start my 2006 Trailblazer the headlights come on, then a few minutes later they go off and I have to use the high beams. Anyone have an answer?

Comment: I'm wondering if the low beam relay is bad? Gets heated up, then disengages. You could possibly swap out the relay for the high side one to see of this might fix the issue.

Comment: Yup, I agree with @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2. My friends trailblazer had this issue. I found a non-critical nearby relay of the same type, popped it in to test, and the low beams worked again.

Comment: A quick test of @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2's theory would be to listen carefully for a click as the lights go off. Wondering if you have to have the engine running for the problem to occur? Or will it also happen a couple of minutes after you turn the lights on? If you don't need the engine running it will be easier to hear the relay click on and off.

Comment: Voting to close, OP isn't responding to comments and there isn't enough information in the question to pursue it with any focus – could be the relay (is there a relay), it could be a self-resetting circuit breaker, or ...?